# 'undefined' Unexpected on Array Loop + charAt

Tags: javascript, html

In this code I write line by line every word of the textarea, separated by white space, but on the last word `undefined` appears and I don't know why

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("separar");

  btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    palavrasSeparadas();
  }, false);
}

var c = new Array();

function palavrasSeparadas() {
  var t2 = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
    //charAt retorna o caracter daquela posição
    c[i] = t2.charAt(i);
  }

  var conteudo = "";
  for (var j = 0; j <= c.length; j++) {
    if (c[j] != ' ') {
      conteudo += c[j];
    } else {
      conteudo += "<br>"
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("msgS").innerHTML = conteudo;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <textarea id="texto" name="texto"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="separar" name="separar" value="Separação">
</form>
<br>
<div id="msgS"></div>
<br>
```

Comment: change `j <= c.length` to `j < c.length` also you can do `document.getElementById("separar").onclick=palavrasSeparadas;`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop goes one value too far. With `j <= c.length` in the last loop execution, when j = c.length, you try to access `c` at `c.length`. But as array index starts with 0, your array is only `c.length-1` long. Use `j < c.length` in the loop.

```
    for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
        if (c[j] != ' ') {
            conteudo += c[j];
        }else {
            conteudo += "<br>"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you use less than or equal to rather than just less than. As such, you are also trying to print the index at c.length, which is undefined. Instead, you should write:

```
for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
    if (c[j] != ' ') {
        conteudo += c[j];
    }else {
        conteudo += "<br>"
    }
```

}

This is a fencepost error.